# About the usage of sed awk grep

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Everyone, what command line should I use to achieve this effect?

This is trying to use awk and sed but failed. Please advise.

```
Original:
server=/example-a.com/127.0.0.1#5353
ipset=/example-a.com/router
server=/example-b.com/127.0.0.1#5353
ipset=/example-b.com/router
server=/example-c.com/127.0.0.1#5353
ipset=/example-c.com/router

Achieve effect:
server=/example-a.com/127.0.0.1#5353
server=/example-a.com/127.0.0.2#5354
ipset=/example-a.com/router
server=/example-b.com/127.0.0.1#5353
server=/example-b.com/127.0.0.2#5354
ipset=/example-b.com/router
server=/example-c.com/127.0.0.1#5353
server=/example-c.com/127.0.0.2#5354
ipset=/example-c.com/router
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need arithmetic, I would go with `awk`:

```
awk -F'[#.]' '/^server/ { print $0, ORS $1"."$2"."$3"."$4"."$5+1"#"$6+1 } !/^server/'
```

Output:

```
server=/example-a.com/127.0.0.1#5353 
server=/example-a.com/127.0.0.2#5354
ipset=/example-a.com/router
server=/example-b.com/127.0.0.1#5353 
server=/example-b.com/127.0.0.2#5354
ipset=/example-b.com/router
server=/example-c.com/127.0.0.1#5353 
server=/example-c.com/127.0.0.2#5354
ipset=/example-c.com/router
```